# Tensorflow-gpu issue (CUDA runtime error: device kernel image is invalid)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I have a python virtual environment (conda) where I’ve installed CUDA toolkit 10.1.243 and tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0rc0. My CUDA driver is 11.0.

In order to test if tensorflow was installed to GPU correctly, I ran a series of commands from within the venv:

`tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()`

True

`tf.config.list_physical_devices(‘GPU’)`

Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro M2000M computeCapability: 5.0
[PhysicalDevice(name=’/physical_device:GPU:0’, device_type=‘GPU’)]

`python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000,1000])))"`

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: device kernel image is invalid

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this. I have a feeling that it is related to modifying the compilation such that tensorflow supports the compute capability of my device (5.0), but I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem. I downgraded the Tensorflow2.3 version to 2.2 with following command.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.2
```

It is working now but very slow.

Answer (score 4):

According to this github issue's explanation, Google Tensorflow engineering team already discarded the support for some older version's GPUs:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41990

I believe your GPU is in those lower versions GPU family.
So downgrading your TF from 2.3. to 2.2 is a solution. And TF engineers suggest us to build the TF2.3 by ourselves and and change its building configuration scripts to enable lower versions GPUs supoort, but Google TF team doesn't confirm it could work, and no resposbility to fix any problem we'll encounter.

Comment: I got rtx 2080, it's pretty weird they are not supporting this device.

Comment: @SidKaushik Yes, it's weird, but I finally totally fixed this problem by switching my environment from TF to pytorch, TF is really a failure SW stack from google, at least it frustrated me many many times.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2`

Comment: Maybe add more explanations to explain how this answers the question?

Comment: what i want to say is instead of just `pip install tensorflow==2.2` use `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2`